# create table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I do not understand what is wrong with this query? Query tool does not want to create a table in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
article_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
article_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
article_desc text NOT NULL,
date_added datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (article_id)
);
```

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 41

Comment: I also get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: article_id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,

Answer (score 152, accepted):

First the `bigint(20) not null auto_increment` will not work, simply use `bigserial primary key`. Then `datetime` is `timestamp` in PostgreSQL. All in all:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    article_id bigserial primary key,
    article_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    article_desc text NOT NULL,
    date_added timestamp default NULL
);
```

Comment: On why, `auto_increment` is a MySQL feature.  Postgres uses `serial` columns for the same purpose.

Comment: @BradKoch: Yes and no. PostgreSQL offers `serial` and `bigserial`. Since the Q contains `bigint(20)` I had chosen `bigserial` in my answer. This is a better match in this case.

Comment: Given OP's apparent use case as a blog article engine, a maximum serial size of 2 billion entries (serial) should be sufficient unless he is extremely prolific. ;) But, still, bigserial is a closer match to bigint.

Answer (score 8):

```
-- Table: "user"

-- DROP TABLE "user";

CREATE TABLE "user"
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  email character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "user"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `bigint(20) not null auto_increment` by `bigserial not null` and 
`datetime` by `timestamp`

Comment: Then create table will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

To create N tables with a prefix use this script.
This code uses a for loop and variable to creates 10 table starting with prefix 'sbtest' namely sbtest1, sbtest2 ... sbtest10

create_table.sql

```
do $$
    DECLARE myvar integer;
begin
    for myvar in 1..10 loop
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE sbtest%s (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        k INTEGER NOT NULL,
        c CHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        pad CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id))', myvar);
    end loop;
end; $$
```

Command to run: psql -U user_name -d database_name -f create_table.sql

Command: \d+ sbtest

```
id | k | c | pad
----+---+---+-----
(0 rows)

                                                   Table "public.sbtest1"
 Column |      Type      | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage  | Stats
 target | Description
--------+----------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+----------+------
--------+-------------
 id     | integer        |           | not null | nextval('sbtest1_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
        |
 k      | integer        |           | not null |                                     | plain    |
        |
 c      | character(120) |           | not null |                                     | extended |
        |
 pad    | character(60)  |           | not null |                                     | extended |
        |
Indexes:
    "sbtest1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Access method: heap
```

Answer (score -5):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
  article_id bigint(20) NOT NULL serial,
  article_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  article_desc text NOT NULL,
  date_added datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (article_id)
);
```

Comment: `bigint(20) ` is invalid in Postgres. Additionally you can't specify `bigint` **and** `serial` at the same time. See the accepted answer for the correct syntax