# doctrine 2.0 : use SQL timestamp

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, timestamp

I'm looking for a way to make doctrine using `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` for MySql.

Additionaly I need to set `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default values.

I would like to have the possibility to have all this code in PHP annotations to have everything in one central place.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing like using `TIMESTAMP` in mysql with Doctrine.
However, I fixed it myself but have to test it:

- Create a file: `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TimestampType.php`
- Copy the code from `TimeType.php` into `TimestampType.php`
- Rename 'Time' to 'Timestamp' in the code
- Create a new constant, and add timestamp to the typesmap in: `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.php`
- Create function called `getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL` in `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform.php`
- And in that function, return `TIMESTAMP`

I've used `yaml` to create my Entities and Proxies, so use in `yaml`:

```
type: timestamp
```

I'm going to test this 'fix'/'workaround' now. I'll let you know.

Comment: Guys, check @david-soussan answer too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888426/1751591

Answer (score 28):

After hours of searching, I found the answer and I hope this helps anyone else looking for a more satisfactory solution than entity lifecycles and the WRONG column type (because a `TIMESTAMP` is a particular type with specific behaviours beyond just storing a `datetime` value)

All you need to do is to add

```
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Version
```

to your annotation and Doctrine will both create a `TIMESTAMP` column with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and then return the actual table value as a valid `\DateTime` object.

[CTOP (Credits to Original Poster)](http://www.franzdeleon.me/2013/11/tip-how-to-add-timestamp-with.html)

Comment: Why without Version it creates DateTime but with Version it creates Timestamp?

Comment: For that you would have to ask the people who wrote it.

Comment: The `version` attribute is flag to tell Doctrine that it can change the value in this column to keep track of where concurrent writes may impact the row data prior to the end of long running transaction.  See [Optimistic Locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking). It is perhaps not a good idea to adopt this attribute for the sake of tripping Doctrine to use `timestamp` for your column.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by [Daniel Criconet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379378/4287833),

`@ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")`

will make that particular column in the corresponding MySQL table become `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.

For YAML version, see the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379378/4287833).

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="timestamp default current_timestamp")
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp")
 */
protected $updatedAt;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Polichism provided the right logic, but the patch wasn't accepted.  Instead, users were directed to add a custom type.  I've implemented that by combining:

- The logic in @Polichism's patch
- [Doctrine's recommended Custom Mapping Types code](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)
- Zf2 Application Configuration instructions found [here](http://www.daredevel.com/working-with-datetime-in-doctrine2-and-zend-framework-2/)

The final versions can be found on GitHub:

- [Timestamp Class](https://github.com/claytondaley/LegacyRS/blob/7822b76726c81920a36c621b4fe5836d43caf630/src/LegacyRS/Type/TimestampType.php)
- See the 'doctrine' part of the [Configuration](https://github.com/claytondaley/LegacyRS/blob/7822b76726c81920a36c621b4fe5836d43caf630/config/module.config.php#L58)

**NOTE:** I've linked to specific commits to ensure that the links remain valid if the file is later removed.  Use the history to check for newer versions.

Comment: How did you solved field TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL when column is nullable issue? I've created custom type and it looks like working fine, but when I use doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql it generates "fieldName TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL" which is not a valid value for TIMESTAMP. Correct syntax is: "filedName TIMESTAMP NULL". Looks like I'll have to override the Platform implementation... any other ideas?

Comment: Frankly, I didn't --dump-sql to create my tables.  The syntax also seems to be [valid for pgSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9826915/1978687).  For [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html), the syntax `timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL` seems to be valid as well.  To get Doctrine to add that first `NULL`, first try the `nullable` attribute in the [@Column annotation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column).  Worst case, use the (non-portable) `columnDefinition` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false ) */
    protected $created;
```

this will create timestamp and return datetime object

```
 public function __construct()
        {
            $this->created = new \DateTime();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`/**
 * @Column(type="datetime", options={"default": 0})
 * @version=true
 */
private $data;`

create sql like this:

`data TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL`

tested on version 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

@ORM\Version works only for one property per entity so it is not an option if you need to have more than one timestamp field in a table.